# CakePHP 2.0 pagination and sum on hasMany-associated model

Tags: cakephp

```
Project hasMany Comments
Payment (id, project_id, value, date)
```

I want to include in my index view a column equal to the sum of payments per project. I want to be able to sort by this field.

I've found some similiar problems here but neither of them concerns pagination.

My current (wrong) solution:

```
    $this->paginate = array('Project' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Project.archived =' => $archive),
            'order' => 'Project.start_date DESC',
            'contain' => array(
                    'Payment' => array(
                            'fields' => array('SUM(Payment.value) as Project__value_sum'),
                            'group'  => array('Payment.project_id'),
                            )
                        )
        ));
    $data = $this->paginate('Project');
    $this->set('projects', $data);
    $this->set('archive', $archive);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you'll probably want to do an [afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#ModelBehavior%3a%3aafterSave) on the `Payment` model.

Within the afterSave function, you run some MySQL that totals the payments (using MySQL SUM()) for the related Project, and store it in Project.payment_total.

Then, you can easily sort by that field, and it keeps you from having to run complex MySQL on every page, since it will only run when necessary (ie when there's a new or changed payment)

Comment: I've noticed it before, however, I want to keep a SUM of payments, not a COUNT of payment.

Comment: @milosz - I edited my answer after realizing that I miss-read your question.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. However, I find it ridiculous that CakePHP does not allow an easy way to execute a simple query with an aggregate function and group by.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do it the way you were trying as well (not that you'd want to, but...), just not sure how offhand.  Maybe using Join instead of Contain?  I think Contain uses multiple queries, so - going the JOIN route instead should allow you to do what you were trying.  (but just guessing on that part)